# error en mi ajax, solo hace la funcion que esta en success de ajax si hago una parada en mi navegador

Tags: javascript, ajax

Mi ajax inserta datos y hace todo bien en el php osea no muestra ningun error, cuando lo ejecuto en el navegador chrome no ejecuta la función, no me muestra el alert ni ejecuta ninguna función que este en el success, pero en firefox muestra el alert pero demasiado rapido y desaparece solo, la única forma de ver el alert es haciendo un paso a paso y/o un breakpoint en source de navegador.

este es mi codigo ajax

```
function registro() {

var nom = $("#nom").val();
var ape = $("#ape").val();


var parametros = {
    "nom": nom, 
    "ape": ape, 
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'modelo/registro.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: parametros, 
    success:function(datos){
        var data = datos.mensaje;
        if (data == "1") {
            alert("exito");
        } else {
            alert("error");
        }
    },
    error:function(e){
        alert("ERROR EN AJAX");
    }
});  
}
```

este es mi codigo php

```
<?php

include("Conexion.php");   

$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$ape = $_POST['ape'];    

$registros = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO registro(nombre, Apellido) 
VALUES ('$nom','$ape')");

 if (!$registros) {
  $mensaje = "0";
}

else{
  $mensaje = "1";
}


$respuestaValidacion = array();
$respuestaValidacion["mensaje"] = $mensaje;
$respuesta = json_encode($respuestaValidacion);
echo $respuesta;
?>
```

este es mi index, el formulario esta dentro de un modal y se ejecuta por medio de una función cuando detecte el onclick del botón registrar

```
<div class="modal-body" id="formReg"><br>
<form method="POST" id="formRegistros">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group col-md-6">
            <input id="nom" type="text" name="nom" minlength="2" required/>
            <label for="nom"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Nombre</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="ape" name="ape" minlength="2" required/>
            <label><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> Apellido</label>                           
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnReg" onclick="registro()" disabled="false">REGISTRAR</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">CERRAR</button>
    </div>
</form> 
</div>
```

Comment: Nunca te lo muestra o te lo muestra despues de un tiempo??

Comment: solo lo muestra en el navegador de firefox pero un segundo y se desaparece solo, es como si pasar demasiado rápido. pero cuando hago paradas en el source de mi navegador si muestra el alert y hace todo lo que ponga en el success

Comment: Cuando haces paradas en el source de tu navegador??, como asi paradas??, pones un debugger??

Comment: @Riven yo creo que se refiere a un breakpoint

Comment: si solo cuando hago un breakpoint hace la función

Comment: Intenta poner un console.log con el valor de datos. antes de pasar por el if. Para ver si te retorna los datos de forma correcta. Otra cosa ¿Esto se esta llamando desde un botón o al cargar la pagina?

Comment: Creo que lo que pasa es que en algun momento el obtiene un error y por eso no llega al sucess, que de una u otra forma debe de si o si mostrar un alert, puesto que hay un if y un else... y en ambos hay un alert.

Comment: @Bell Es extraño que no te muestre ningún alert, ya que tienes alert para el caso ok y de error, ademas cuando se muestra un alert la ejecución del código js se detiene hasta que no se acepta el alert. Puede examinar que te retorna el php mirando con F12 en el navegador en la pestaña network.

Comment: Probablemente estás trabajando con un formulario y usas AJAX para procesarlo, pero falta evitar que el formulario continúe con su proceso normal. Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código donde ejecutas la función `registro()`

Comment: @Riven, Pero es muy raro porque si lo ejecuto en el navegador Firefox muestra el alert por un segundo y se desaparece solo, es como si pasara demasiado rápido

Comment: @Triby, ya agregue el codigo html. por favor ayuda!!!!!

Comment: @DarkFrostnight si ya lo he hecho, y me muestra el 1 o el 0.
normalmente lo hago asi: ' console.log(data); '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @Bell Considera cambiar la propiedad `type="submit"` el siguiente código de HTML como sigue:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnReg" onclick="registro()" disabled="false">REGISTRAR</button>
```

Esto previene que al finalizar JavaScript de ejecutar la función `registro()` no realice la función por defecto de submit de los botones de tipo submit.

Eso mismo hace que la ventana te cargue por un tiempo de milisegundos, despues te haga el submit para la misma página.

Otra opción es hacer el cambio utilizando JavaScript como sigue:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnReg" onclick="registro(this)" disabled="false">REGISTRAR</button>
```

Por lo que en el JavaScript tu función debe quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
function registro(event) {  
    //to codigo
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Esto hará que se detenga la función por Defecto de submit del button.

Espero te sirva la información.

Comment: gracias ya pude solucionarlo, era por el type="submit" lo cambie como dijiste a type="button" y ya me funciona

Comment: Excelente, @bell si la respuesta te resulto útil, te pido que la marques como correcta. Saludos...

Answer (score 0):

Un formulario se puede procesar por hacer clic en el botón de envío `submit` o por presionar la tecla `ENTER` y, por eso, es mejor asignar el evento al formulario y no solo al botón. En este caso, el evento `onsubmit`, que va a capturar ambas opciones.

Como parámetro se envía el evento para poder detener su ejecución con `.preventDefault()`, si este el formulario se procesa normalmente, es decir, recargando (o cargando) la página especificada en la acción.

Como no especificaste el atributo `action`, el navegador procesará el formulario en la misma página, por eso es que no podías ver la alerta o se cerraba.

```js
// Esta función se ejecuta después de que se carga la página
$(function() {
    // Asignar evento a formulario
    $("#formRegistros").on('submit', function(e) { registro(e); });
});

function registro(event) {
    // Evitar comportamiento normal del formulario
    // manteniendo todo en esta misma página
    event.preventDefault();

    var parametros = {
        "nom": $("#nom").val(), 
        "ape": $("#ape").val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'modelo/registro.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: parametros, 
        success:function(datos){
            var data = datos.mensaje;
            if (data == "1") {
                alert("exito");
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        },
        error:function(e){
            alert("ERROR EN AJAX");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body" id="formReg"><br>
<form method="POST" id="formRegistros">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group col-md-6">
            <input id="nom" type="text" name="nom" minlength="2" required/>
            <label for="nom"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Nombre</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="ape" name="ape" minlength="2" required/>
            <label><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> Apellido</label>                           
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnReg" >REGISTRAR</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">CERRAR</button>
    </div>
</form> 
</div>
```

Comment: pude solucionar solo cambiando el ´type = "submit"´ pot ´type = "button"´ y ya funciona, mil gracias por la atencion